# Moment auto set locale after importing the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, locale, translation

I need to design a dropdown of languages where we click at one language , it will change all date format in that page following the chosen country's format.

So basically i'm using moment.js to do it with my React app. My idea is when I choose a language, it will call the function `moment.locale( language )` and then all the date format I use in the page will change

For example if I want to change to french . this is my expected output

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
console.log(moment.locale()); //expected output: en , actual output: fr 
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment.locale()); //expected output: fr , actual output: fr
```

So my problem is the locale will change to `fr` without the need of `moment.locale('fr')`.

I do some experiment and realize that by importing the locale data `import 'moment/locale/fr';` It will automatically set the locale to `fr` without the need of `moment.locale('fr')`. Which I dont want because I only want to set it after click some button. But at the same time I also need to load this locale data for the `moment.js` to translate correctly.
Anyone experience this ?? Thanks

Comment: I would import all locales you need at once.

Comment: @JanCiołek if I import all locales , it will automatically set the locale of the last import

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can import and set up locales like this

**Moment Config**

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import 'moment/locale/en';
import moment from 'moment';

//set up default locale
moment.locale('en')
```

**Component1**

```
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'

class Component1 extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
      moment.locale('fr')
    }

}
```

Tell me if this is somewhat working solution.

Cheers!

Comment: This will solve the issue by setting it to 'en' whenever the page loads. However, it will get trouble because later , what I want is the browser to remember the previous language choice of user